# Issues passing arguments to a python script

Tags: python

I have a python script that I want to pass command line arguments.   I have taken some guidance from [Windows Python Naming Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686083/windows-python-name-error) and [Python Command Line Arguments Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm).  I don't have any errors that pop up when executing the script, however I don't get the expected error message when no command line arguments are given, nor do I get the print command when the -h command line is given.  I have added print commands to the -i and the -s command line arguments as well and have not been able to ever successfully pull through any of the command line arguments (although no errors)  I am at a loss why this isn't working, as I am not that experienced with Python.   I would be grateful if anyone could point the issue out to me.

```
import re
import os
import sys
import getopt

def main(argv):
   ipaddress = ''
   scac = ''
   try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:s:",["ipaddress=","scac="])
   except getopt.GetoptError:
      print 'test.py -i <ipaddress> -s <scac>'
   sys.exit(2)
   for opt, arg in opts:
      if opt == '-h':
         print 'FedConnectStatus.py -i <iobipaddress> -s <scac>'
         sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("-i", "--ipaddress"):
         ipaddress = arg
      elif opt in ("-s", "--scac"):
         scac = arg
```

Comment: what is error msg

Comment: please provide a example input, and the program's behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You not getting the help because you have `sys.exit` on root instead it
  should be inside if block

if you dont pass any option then opts will empty list then you can manually check and perform the action

```
def main(argv):
    #print argv
    ipaddress = ''
    scac = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:s:",["ipaddress=","scac="])
        if not opts: # if no option given 
            print 'usage test.py -i <ipaddress> -s <scac>'
            sys.exit(2)
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print 'test.py -i <ipaddress> -s <scac>'
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print 'FedConnectStatus.py -i <iobipaddress> -s <scac>'
            sys.exit() # it should be on level of if
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ipaddress"):
            ipaddress = arg
        elif opt in ("-s", "--scac"):
            scac = arg

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])


#  $ python cmderr.py -h
#  FedConnectStatus.py -i <iobipaddress> -s <scac>
```